# Add div conditionally says The name container does not exist in the current context

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, .net-4.0, asp.net-4.0, inline-code

I want to add HTML div conditionally  in rotator control. I am using the following code but it says "The name container does not exist in the current context" at `DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "COL_ID")`

```
<telerik:RadRotator ID="rtrList" runat="server" Width="830px" Height="100px"
                FrameDuration="10" RotatorType="ButtonsOver" ScrollDuration="450" WrapFrames="true"
                ItemWidth="100" ItemHeight="80" >
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hdfId" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("COL_ID") %>' />

                    <div id="div" runat="server" title='<%# Eval("NAME") %>' class="widget_item">

                        <span>
                            <%# Eval("TITLE") %>
                        </span>
                    </div>

                <%if (Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "COL_ID")) % 2 == 0)

                   {%>

                    <div></div>

                <%} %>    

                </ItemTemplate>


            </telerik:RadRotator>
```

Please guide me where I am wrong. as I am using DataBinder.Eval & Container.DataItem for the first time.

Regards,
Kash

Answer (score 0):

The error implies that this data item does not exist in the item bound to the control.

For example.   If you were binding to a table, the table must have a column called "Col_ID" or this will throw an error.

Can you add your code for binding the control to the data source?

Comment: binding using DataSource property.
rtrList.DataSource = list;

I am getting error on design time

Comment: How are you setting your list?

Comment: list is a DataTable which is populated from Database.

Comment: @Kash - have you confirmed that DataTable contains a column named "COL_ID"?   Simply run debug, stop on the line where you bind, and inspect the datatable.

Answer (score 0):

Use this syntax instead of the if:

```
<%# (Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "COL_ID")) % 2 == 0) ? "<div></div>" : "" %>
```